# A room comprised only of mirrors

Tags: visible-light

What would be seen if a room of perfectly transperant 1 way mirrors was constructed (no visible edging or imperfections). On the outside of every mirror is perfectly even white lighting and a camera that does not interupt the lighting. 
What would an image from the camera capture? 
What would happen with lighting changes?
 What if only one wall had lighting on the exterior?

Comment: I looked at this question but it does not contain the answers I am curious to find. I would like to know what image the camera would capture. Not being a physicist I am guessing that the image would be blinding white light.

Comment: I have edited the post to extend upon what I hope to learn

Comment: You are asking an open-ended, hypothetical "What would happen if I did this...?" type of question. The [help centre](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) explains that such questions are not useful on this site.

Comment: How can I ammend this?

Comment: Sam, you could improve your question by explaining why you think you might see something different from "blinding white light." Do you think  there is a fault in your understanding somewhere? If so, what is it? Why do you think a physicist might give some other answer? What difference to you think a single wall of lighting would make? Why do you think your answer might be wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know the answer to any of these questions (hence why I asked it). If it is in the wrong format for this website you may delete or suspend it as I have received an acceptable answer

Comment: Well if you are satisfied with the answer of "blinding white light," and you don't have any reason to think it might be wrong, I don't understand why you are asking on Physics SE. The purpose of the site is to explain things you don't understand, not to confirm that the obvious answer is correct. If the only thing available for the camera to see is  "even white lighting" reflected in mirrors, what reason have you got for thinking a physicist might give you a different answer?

Comment: I was seeking conformation as I have only slight physics knowledge but from thinking it through came to this conclusion. I had no idea if there was a law/s I did not know of  eg. how 1 way mirrors work. This was explained well In the first answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly transparent one way mirrors are impossible because light travels in reversible paths. A practical one way mirror relies on having more light on one side than the other. So if you put the lights outside of the room, you could see then from inside the room. The camera will see the outside lighting from the other side as well as a ton of reflected light.

On a related note: there is a device known as a lab sphere which is a sphere with a white interior and one or two small holes. Light is supposed to bounce around inside the sphere many times before finding its way out. This mixes the light into a nice uniform source so that you can, for example, provide even lighting to a bundle of fiber optic cables.